# UIStackView animating from left when isHidden == true

Tags: xcode, jquery-animate, uistackview

I have a UIStackView with a bunch of arrangedSubviews. I want them all to be hidden on viewDidLoad so I go and do

```
public func setStackViewHidden(_ isHidden: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    stackView.arrangedSubviews.forEach ({ subview in
        if animated {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                subview.isHidden = isHidden
            }
        } else {
            subview.isHidden = isHidden
        }
    })
}
```

This makes the whole stackView hidden. When I then go and use the same method with isHidden == false. It animates from the left and expands to the right to the correct size. Why doesn't it animate from the correct width to the bottom, but rather from the left to the whole size?

Comment: Depending on how you have your constraints set up, when all views are hidden the stack view has no intrinsic size. So, when the subviews are "un-hidden" the animation begins before the sizes are set. Try giving your first arranged subview a width constraint and see if you get the results you want.

Comment: Did not help, maybe overriding intristicSize in my stackview would help.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in animation `UIStackView` uses when an arranged subview is shown / hidden can work well --- and it can be not-so-great.

One of the key things a stack view does is **arrange its subviews**. Of course, one often also uses the width and height of the subviews to determine the width and height of the stack view. So we can end up with undefined states, and the animation - as you've seen - gets "wonky."

Give this a try (all code, no `@IBOutlets` or `@IBActions`, so just assign a view controller to this class):

```
class StackShowHideViewController: UIViewController {

    // UIButton
    let btn: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.setTitle("Tap Me", for: .normal)
        v.backgroundColor = .red
        return v
    }()

    // vertical UIStackView
    let stackView: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.axis = .vertical
        v.alignment = .fill
        v.distribution = .fill
        v.spacing = 8
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // add elements to view
        view.addSubview(btn)
        view.addSubview(stackView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // constrain button 20-pts from top, centered horizontally
            btn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            btn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),

            // constrain stack view 20-pts from bottom of button
            // centered horizontally
            // width constrained to 160-pts
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160.0),

        ])

        // add 5 UILabels to the stack view
        for i in 1...5 {
            let v = UILabel()
            v.backgroundColor = .yellow
            v.text = "This is Label \(i)"
            v.textAlignment = .center
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            // inititially hidden
            v.isHidden = true
            // add label to stack view
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(v)
            // constrain label widths to width of stack view
            v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        }

        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    public func setStackViewHidden(_ isHidden: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        stackView.arrangedSubviews.forEach ({ subview in
            if animated {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                    subview.isHidden = isHidden
                }
            } else {
                subview.isHidden = isHidden
            }
        })
    }

    @objc func didTap(_ sender: Any) {
        // if labels are hidden, show them
        // else, hide them
        var h = true
        if let v = stackView.arrangedSubviews.first {
            h = v.isHidden
        }
        setStackViewHidden(!h, animated: true)
    }

}
```